# determine software installed in computer using php/javascript

Tags: php, javascript

is there a way to detect what software is installed in computer using php/javascript or any plugin.

what i want to do is if a client open our site using firefox or ie and our web detected that chrome is installed, the chrome will open automatically directing to our site.

Comment: If this was possible, I'd never visit your website or use a browser that allows this.

Comment: The closest solution would be to check the browser (in PHP you would check $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) and if it's not Chrome, pop up a message suggesting they open it in Chrome.

Comment: If you're worried about cross browser compatibility, then ensure cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that. That would be a huge security risk.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible, not unless you ask the user to install and run client-side software written using something other than JavaScript. To allow otherwise would be a large security and privacy risk.